# Inconsistent outcomes from Tkinter Checkbutton code

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I am wring a small app in python/tkinter and have a screen with two checkboxes that impact how the date is processed. I want both boxes to have a default position to checked or selected and the following seemingly identical code establishes the opening position of each.

I am struggling to see any difference between the two sets of statements - I am pretty sure I probably copied one block to create the other - yet when the code runs the first checkbox defaults to selected but the second is unchecked.

I am importing both tkinter as * and ttk but I believe these to be instances of the tkinter basic Checkbutton.

Any comments or pointers as to why two seemingly identical sets of code should react differently would be gratefully received.

```
    var_ignore_clsd = IntVar()
    chk_ignore_clsd = Checkbutton(aBlock, text='Ignore closed orders', variable=var_ignore_clsd)
    chk_ignore_clsd.grid(sticky=W, row=0, column=6, padx=(5,0), pady=(8,0))
    chk_ignore_clsd.configure(bg=param_value[1])
    chk_ignore_clsd.select()
    var_close_after = IntVar()
    chk_close_after = Checkbutton(aBlock, text='Close order when invoice processed', variable=var_close_after)
    chk_close_after.grid(sticky=W, row=7, column=4, padx=(5,0), pady=(8,0), columnspan=2)
    chk_close_after.configure(bg=param_value[1])
    chk_close_after.select()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue using your code.  Are the two checkbuttons actually created in different place in your code?

Comment: No those 10 lines are continuous. The number of lines prevented me showing the entire function that creates the screen.

Comment: I am going to CANCEL this question as further checking makes me think it is a quirk of my system. Printing the value of both variables to the console immediatiely after the above code shows both with a value of 1, ie the checked value. Back to the "drawing board" for now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def display_input():
   print("Input for Python:", var_ignore_clsd.get())
   print("Input for C++:", var_close_after.get())

var_ignore_clsd = tk.IntVar()
chk_ignore_clsd = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Ignore closed orders', variable=var_ignore_clsd, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
chk_ignore_clsd.grid(sticky=tk.W, row=0, column=6, padx=(5,0), pady=(8,0))
chk_ignore_clsd.configure(bg=param_value[1])
chk_ignore_clsd.select()

var_close_after = tk.IntVar()
chk_close_after = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Close order when invoice processed', variable=var_close_after, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
chk_close_after.grid(sticky=tk.W, row=7, column=4, padx=(5,0), pady=(8,0), columnspan=2)
chk_close_after.configure(bg=param_value[1])
chk_close_after.select()

root.mainloop()
```

Result screenshot:

[image]